# Not getting radio button value php

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, insert

So i did a survey , the only problem that i have is that i get two times the value of the commentary . The thing is that i want is :for every question get  value of the radio button and value of the commentary . Any help or advices are welcome.

Here is an example  of the echo :

```
choix = test1 
comment = test1

INSERT INTO questionnaire(Choix,Commentara) VALUES('test1','test1')
```

So obviously i don't get radio button values . But two times the value of textarea that i write ''test1''.

[screenshot to help you understand](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/240225788715204609/280601943145971712/unknown.png)

Here is my code for to display to the custommer the survey and  to insert custommer marks and commentaries :

```
  <?php
    $link=Mysqli_connect($host,$login,$pass,$dbname);
    $un = 0;
    $kv = 0 ;
    $msgerror = "Veuillez remplir tous les champs ";    

    if(isset($_POST["bouton10"])){



        $id = !empty($_REQUEST["Picolo4"]) ? $_REQUEST["Picolo4"] : "";
        $Nom = !empty($_REQUEST["Picolo1"]) ? $_REQUEST["Picolo1"] : "";
        $Prenom = !empty($_REQUEST["Picolo2"]) ? $_REQUEST["Picolo2"] : "";
        $Email = !empty($_REQUEST["Picolo3"]) ? $_REQUEST["Picolo3"] : "";
        $RefClient = !empty($_REQUEST["Picolo5"]) ? $_REQUEST["Picolo5"] : "";
        if ($id !="" && $Nom !="" && $Prenom !="" && $Email !="" && $RefClient !=""){

            $recherche= "SELECT Ref,Question,Choix,Commentara FROM questionnaire WHERE Qref ='$id'";


            mysqli_query($link,$recherche);





            $result= mysqli_query($link,$recherche);
            $num_results = $result->num_rows;
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

                $Ref =$row["Ref"];
                $Question       =$row["Question"];

                $un++;
                $kv++;

                echo" <tr bgcolor=\"white\">

                <td>$Question  </td>
                <td>
                    3<input type=\"radio\" name =\"$un\" id =\"un\" value = \"3\">
                    2<input type=\"radio\" name =\"$un\" id =\"un\" value = \"2\">
                    1<input type=\"radio\" name =\"$un\" id =\"un\" value = \"1\">
                    0<input type=\"radio\" name =\"$un\" id =\"un\"  value = \"0\">
                    PA<input type=\"radio\" name =\"$un\" id =\"un\" value = \"PA\">
                </td>
                <td width = \"60\"> <textarea name =\"$kv\" id =\"kv\" rows=\"5\" placeholder=\"Votre commentaire\"></textarea> </td> 
            </tr>


        </div>
    </div>
    "; 

    }
    }
    else {

        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$msgerror')</script>";

    }
    }

    $kv = 1;
    $un = 1;
    $i= 1 ;

    if (isset($_POST["bouton11"]))   {





        while(isset($_POST[$un])||(isset($_POST[$kv]))){
            $choix = $_POST["$un"];
            $comment = $_POST["$kv"];


            $enregistrer = "INSERT INTO questionnaire(Choix,Commentara)  VALUES('$choix','$comment') ";

            $un++;
            $kv++;
            $i++;
            echo"$choix";
            echo "$comment";
            echo"$enregistrer";
            mysqli_query($link, $enregistrer); 

        }
    //Besoin d'un correctif

        //while(isset($_POST[$kv])) {
        //  $comment = $_POST["$kv"];


        //  $enregistrer2 = "INSERT INTO questionnaire(Commentara) VALUES('$comment')";
           // $kv++;

         // echo"$enregistrer2";

        //  mysqli_query($link, $enregistrer2);
        //}

    }



    ?>
```

Here is the form:

```
<DOCTYPE HTML>
   <HTML>
      <HEAD>
         <TITLE>Foredeck_Testeur</TITLE>
         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" charset="utf-8">
         <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
         <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

         <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/footer-distributed-with-address-and-phones.css">
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/tab.css">
         <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cookie" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.css">

         <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="js/tab.js"></script>


         <style type="text/css">
          .footer {
             min-width: 100%;
             height: auto;
             text-align: center;
             background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
             position: fixed;
             bottom: 0%;
             margin-top: 50%;
          }

          .wrapper {
             min-height: 100%;
             height: auto !important;
             height: 100%;
             margin: 0 auto -142px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
          }




       </STYLE>


    </HEAD>


    <BODY bgcolor="#6495ED">
      <form method ="post" >

         <table class="center-table" border ="1" align="center" >

            <tr bgcolor="#b0bffc">   
               <td>Nom:</TD><TD><input type="text" class="form-control" name ="Picolo1" id="Picolo1" > </textarea></td><td><P>(Obligatoire*)</P></td>  




            </tr>
            <tr bgcolor="#b0bffc">
               <td>Prénom:</TD><TD><input type="text" class="form-control" name ="Picolo2" id="Picolo2"> </textarea></td><td><P>(Obligatoire*)</P></td>
            </tr>
            <tr bgcolor="#b0bffc">
               <td>Email:</TD><TD><input type="mail" class="form-control" name ="Picolo3" id="Picolo3"> </textarea></td><td><P>(Obligatoire*)</P></td>
            </tr>

            <tr bgcolor="#b0bffc">
               <td>Référence Questionnaire:</td>
               <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name ="Picolo4" id="Picolo4" > </textarea></td> <td> (Obligatoire*)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr bgcolor="#b0bffc">
               <td>Référence Client:</td>
               <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name ="Picolo5" id="Picolo5" > </textarea></td> <td> (Obligatoire*)</td>
            </tr>
            <Tr>
               <TD bgcolor="#b0bffc">
                  <Center><button type="submit" name="bouton10" id="bouton10" class="btn btn-default" >Confirmer</button></Center>
               </TD>
            </TR>
         </table>
         <BR>

            <table class="center-table" border ="1" align="center"  >

               <tr bgcolor="#b0bffc">   <td> Question</td> <td>Choix</td> <td>Commentaires</td>   </tr>

               <?php
               include("bdconnect_Foredeck.php");
               include("foredeckaffiche_client.php");
               include("foredeck_insert_client.php");

               ?>

            </Table>
            <BR>


               <Center><button type="submit" name="bouton11" id="bouton11" class="btn btn-default" >Enregistrer</button></Center>
            </BR> 
         </form>
         <BR>
           <BR>
             <Center>
               <a href ="Foredeckmain.php" >Retour</button> </a> 


            </Center>

         </div>
         <div class="footer">
          <p>
             <font color="white"> Foredeck Consulting Ltd &copy;  2017 </font>
          </p>
       </div>
    </BODY>
 </HTML>
```

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: You can't have the same ID on your checkboxes. ID's in HTML must be unique per document/element. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp

Comment: Even if i did change the name it's not working

Comment: test1                                                                                                       test1                                                                                                       INSERT INTO questionnaire(Choix,Commentara) VALUES('test1','test1')

Comment: You're giving all your input elements the same name, which is correct for the radio-inputs, but since you're calling the textarea the same name (san autoincremented value), only that value will be passed along. `$un` and `$kv` will always be the same incremented integer.

Comment: So how i could solve this problem for name of textarea ? Should i autoincremented the id of textarea too ?

Comment: Give it a prefix, like: `text_$kv`.

Comment: For the name only i have to change ? @MagnusEriksson

Comment: omg ty it work @MagnusEriksson

Answer (score 0):

Use class instead id for defining radiobuttons and before first if you should get the value of button10:

```
$bouton10 = $_POST["bouton10"];
```

Comment: The problem here is that the names of all the inputs (including the textarea) all have the same name. Plus, you don't get the class name in the post array so, that would not change the outcome at all.